# Get the plot taking into account censoring for survival analysis

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

(Sorry for the english) I'm currently trying to study the length of sick leaves in administrations and so i have a database where have been put the lengths, dates, and other infos for thousands of leaves. I'm a complete beginner in that type of analysis. In the end i'm supposed to be able to tell the percentage of sick days that happens beyond the x-th day of a sick leave. I'm trying to use the survival analysis package (survival) to simplify my work. So far i'm able to answer my question but I do not take into account censoring. I have a column with 0 for data that has been censored and 1 for data that hasn't. Before anything else i'm trying to get the survival plot of the data where censoring has been corrected. Which if i understood the principle correctly  means that the plot would be the predicted one where every sick leave has reached its end. Here is the code that i'm using but i'm pretty sure i'm not using R the right way. I also don't know if I should even be using cox or something else.

Ok so in time2013 i have the length of my leaves, in event2013 i have the 0s for censored data and 1 for data that isn't. The dataframe with all the data is called mydata.

Is the plot that I get using this code what I'm looking for ?

```
s <- Surv(time2013,event2013)
fKM <- survfit(s ~ 1,data=mydata)
plot(fKM,conf.int=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's probably*** the first thing I would try, but there so many more things to aspects to this....

1) What are you trying to do? Is it purely exploratory, or are you testing some assumptions/theories/hypotheses?

2) Do the censored fields contain people with no sick leave, or just those that have never returned? If they died before the end of the last date of the data period, how does that affect things if you assume those still alive on sick leave are censored in the same way?

3) What other info do you have, and what covariates could you put in the right side of the formula. The person's sex and age might seem worthwhile. Do you have length of service, seniority grade, number of previous sick leave periods?

I'll come back to this....... I have been beckoned to prepare supper :-)

Comment: I wanted to edit this post to answer your questions but once I was done I realised the problem was now entirely different so I answered your questions and updated the status of my issue in [another  post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014180/what-r-packages-or-algortihms-would-you-use-in-that-kind-of-analysis) .